# TNewCheckListBox Checked not being updated

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to write an installer in Inno Setup that includes a page where a `TNewCheckListBox` is created and then used to populate a selection of choices on the next page:

```pascal
var
  ListBox:         TNewCheckListBox;
  SelectedConfigs: array of Integer;

function ConfigurationPage(): Integer;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  I:    Integer;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Select Configuration', 
    'Please select the configuration you would like to install to.');

  ListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
  ListBox.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ListBox.Left := ScaleX(0);
  ListBox.Top := ScaleY(0);
  ListBox.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ListBox.Height := Page.SurfaceHeight;
  ListBox.BorderStyle := bsNone;

  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(ConfigurationNames) - 1 do
  begin
    ListBox.AddCheckBox(
      ConfigurationNames[I], '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  end;

  ListBox.ItemIndex := 0;
  Result := Page.ID;
end;

procedure PortSelectionPage(PageID: Integer);
var
  Page:         TWizardPage;
  ArrayLength:  Integer;
  I:            Integer;
begin

  Page := CreateCustomPage(PageID, 'Select Port', 
    'Please select the port you want the configurations to receive on.');
       
  for I := 0 to ListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Log(Format('ListBox[%d], %s is checked? %d', [
      I, ListBox.Items[I], ListBox.Checked[I]]));
    if ListBox.Checked[I] then
    begin
      ArrayLength := GetArrayLength(SelectedConfigs);
      SetArrayLength(SelectedConfigs, ArrayLength + 1);
      SelectedConfigs[ArrayLength] := I;
      Log(Format('Config %d was selected...', [I]));
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var                         
  PageID:           Integer;
begin
  PageID := ConfigurationPage;                                            
  PortSelectionPage(PageID);
end;
```

The problem I'm having is that, regardless of the selections I make in the `ConfigurationPage` procedure, the `SelectedConfigs` array is not being updated and my debugging messages are showing that none of the options are selected. Before creating the `PortSelectionPage` procedure, the code lived on the `CurStepChanged` event handler so I'm not sure if the issue is with my having moved the code to a different page or if there's something else going on here. Do I need to force an update to the component or should I be using event handlers instead? If so, how would I implement one for this usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole code is executed from [`InitializeWizard` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard). Hence even *before* the installer wizard is shown.

You have to query the checkbox states only *after the user changes* them. For example, from some of these events:

- [`NextButtonClick`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick)
- [`CurStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged)
- [`CurPageChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged)